# sql query what is wrong here?(count inside a max)

Tags: sql, database

```
select store.store_code, store.store_name, max(store.avgR) 
from (select avg(worker.salary) as avgR, worker.store_code, store.store_name
      from worker inner join
           store
           on worker.store_code = store.store_code
      group by worker.store_code
     ) store
```

---

for some reason i get the wrong code and name with the good max average.
can anyone tell me please whats the problem here? thanks.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  You should also explain what you are trying to do, the query is not obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the store with the maximum average salary, you can do something like this:

```
select avg(w.salary) as avgR, s.store_code, s.store_name
from worker w inner join
     store s
     on w.store_code = s.store_code
group by s.store_code, s.store_name
order by avgR desc
limit 1;
```

Notes:

- The unaggregated columns in the `select` should match the `group by`.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Not all databases support `limit`, but I'm guessing that you are using MySQL.